# Logic question - Statement logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given this statement:

> "Every positive number that is smaller than $1$ is bigger than its square"

Which of these statements are true (They may be both false/right) ?

You can write the statement as:

1. $\forall x((x <1) \wedge (x >0) \wedge (x^2 <x))$
2. $\forall x((x<1) \wedge (x>0)) \rightarrow \forall x(x^2 < x)$

I think that $1$ is true as it is a Tautology, but I am not sure about $2$.. ( I am not sure about $1$ as well)

I would appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: $(1)$ is not true if , lets say , $x=2$. In $(2)$, the second "for all" can be removed (and I think, it should)

Comment: @Peter Hey, thank you for your comment. But for $x=2$ for (1) it does not even pass the first $\text{AND}$ ( $ \wedge $ ) then how is it counted as a contradiction? and for (2) , why is removing the second $\forall x$ fixes the statement? Thank you!

Comment: $(1)$ is an and-expression that only holds if all statements hold, which is not the case. The original statement however is true for all real $x$ (it is actually a tautology). In $(2)$ you already have "for all x" such that we have ... , then you need not (and should not) mention it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your statements says what is should.

I would do this:
$$
\forall x\Big(\big((x>0) \wedge (x<1)\big) \rightarrow (x>x^2)\Big)
$$
Or maybe
$$
\forall x \Big((x>0) \rightarrow \big((x<1)\rightarrow (x>x^2)\big)\Big)
$$
These are equivalent statements, and "that is" could be interpreted either way.

Note, I followed your lead and did not put in special language for "is a number" and "square".

---

Our target statement: "Every positive number that is smaller than
$1$ is bigger than its square" is a true statement about the real numbers.

Your statement 1
$$
\forall x((x <1) \wedge (x >0) \wedge (x^2 < x))
$$
says that every number has all three properties: $x<1$ and $x>0$ and $x^2<x$.  That is not what we want.  This is not a true statement about the real numbers.

Your statement 2
$$
\forall x((x<1) \wedge (x>0)) \rightarrow \forall x(x^2 < x)
$$
Is also not what we want.  Interpreted in the real numbers, it means:
**if** every number has both properties $x > 1$ and $x < 0$ (which is false), **then** every number has the property $x^2 < x$ (which is also false).  This conditional statement is, in fact, true about the real numbers, but does not tell us what the target statement does.

Comment: But why they don't say what they should say? I don't understand :( , Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Thank you sir, if we were to remove the second $\forall x$ in (2) would it be correct?

Comment: Yes, it would be correct.  Well, only if you know $x<x^2$ means the same as $x^2>x$.

Comment: But why is it false that a number can have both properties: $x>0$ and $x<1$ as you said at the last paragraph?

Comment: A number can have both properties.  But it says that every number has both properties.  That is false.

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate it!

Comment: Hey one little question, is it the right way to write this statement: $\forall x( 0<x<1 \rightarrow x^2 < x)$ ? Because it seems right but not every number has this property of $0<x<1$ ...